# Joining multiple tables to one table

Tags: sql-server

I have table A, B, C, I want to join these table to be one Table but table A has no linking field with Table B and table C. Table B and table C has.

Comment: Posting a sample of your table structures, some data and the final desired result would be incredibly helpful in answering this question.

Comment: if there is no link, what is the relation between A-B and A-C?

Comment: There is no relation between A-B and A-C

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION ALL, you must name your columns the same though:

```
SELECT COLA1 AS [COMMON_COL1], COLA2 AS [COMMON_COL2]
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT COLB1 AS [COMMON_COL1], COLB2 AS [COMMON_COL2]
FROM B
UNION ALL
SELECT COLC1 AS [COMMON_COL1], COLC2 AS [COMMON_COL2]
FROM C
ORDER BY [COMMON_COL1]
```